# Is it possible to get a natural log of a big-integer instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, math, biginteger

I am using [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) for JavaScript.

```
var bigInt = require('big-integer')
```

I have a bigInt instance:

```
var ratherLargeNumber = bigInt(2).pow(2048)
```

Can I get a (natural) log of it?

Comment: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js/issues/26

Comment: @Bergi Yes, that's me.

Comment: You could probably implement it using a [taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have a big integer `x = 5384932048329483948394829348923849`.

If you convert x to a decimal string and count the digits, you can then represent x by `0.5384932048329483948394829348923849` × 10<sup>34</sup>.

**You want to take the natural logarithm of x**. *Observe the following*.

log<sub>e</sub>(x) = `34` log<sub>e</sub>(`10`) + log<sub>e</sub>(`0.5384932048329483948394829348923849`)

You can now use regular `Number` computations and the regular `Math.log` to perform the computation.

```
var bigInt = require('big-integer');
var integer = bigInt('5384932048329483948394829348923849').toString();
var ln_x = Math.log(10 + integer);
```

Comment: @mikemaccana Note that in the actual library code there may be a more efficient way to do this.  For example, the computation could be done in whatever base BigInteger.js uses internally, instead of in base 10.  After a quick inspection of the library code, it looks like it is storing numbers in base 10 million.  This method will still work fine using that base instead.