# How to calculate logarithm with base N for big integer?

Tags: javascript, math, biginteger, logarithm

I'm using this [BigInteger.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer) for some calculations:

```
let myBigInt = bigInt(20).pow(200) // gets 160693804425899027554196209234116260252220299378279283530137600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I'd like to apply the logarithm to the big integer but in the docs I could not find any matching function. How can I implement a `log(baseN, valueX)` function for the BigInteger.js library?

Note: `let myLogarithm = myBigInt.log(baseN)` is not a valid implementation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418957/is-it-possible-to-get-a-natural-log-of-a-big-integer-instance

Comment: try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get a natural log of a big-integer instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418957/is-it-possible-to-get-a-natural-log-of-a-big-integer-instance)

Comment: @assembler I don't think that would work with objects that aren't numbers (since OP is using a Big Int library) or with numbers that are larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (which OP likely works with, since he has the library).

Comment: @Kittsil - No duplicate because the OP of the linked question tried to calculate the NATURAL log while I'd like to calculate a custom based log.

Comment: @vlaz +1 You're right --> assembler's comment is absolutely not valid because I'm using a bigInt library instead of plain javascript (small integers).

Comment: @vlaz, see the jonas00 own "After a lot of try&error" solution: he is using Math.log, so, it works

Comment: @jonas00 This is absolutely a duplicate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base

Comment: Of course this works - but just with the workaround. **To add on - the conversion in my answer is not really accurate because `"0" + value` after parsing to float just get it's limits.**

Comment: Why bother using bigints if you only want logs to typical floating point precision?

Comment: I **do want** to log bigger values as could be displayed in floating point precision. Sure I do. @JamesKPolk

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Note**: After a lot of try&error I did found a working solution my own and I will post it here because I'm pretty sure there are a few more people then me that also gots faced with the same issue right there. So I hope, I could help :`)`

---

Have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base), as I did because theres a very nice article about baseConversion.

Below you can find a function for `Math.log(base, value)` that is able to calculate the `log(base)` from a value.

```js
Math.log = (function() {
  var log = Math.log;
  return function(base, n) {
    return log(n)/(base ? log(base) : 1);
  };
})();
```

To calculate the `logarithmToBaseN` for bigInt-values just use this line of code:

```
let logarithmToBaseN = (myBigInt.toString().length * Math.log(baseN, 10) + Math.log(baseN, parseFloat("0." + myBigInt))) - 1);
```

---

**Edit**: This soltuion is a tiny **workaround** bacause `parseFloat("0." + myBigInt)` converts a big value like `100000` to a really small one like `0.100000,...` what causes that it will be in integer precision.

---

**According to `@Jonas W`'s comment**: *The solution is very accurate for lower bases like `(5, 10, ...)` combined with low values like `10, 1000, 100000` - but for **really big values** like `bigInt(20).pow(200)` is it not.*

**Note**: Using `parseFloat` (**IEEE 754 double precision** [floating-point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)) means, you have a maximum of **52 bits of precision**, which is a bit more than 15 decimal places. After that - the accuracy will be killed.

**Note:** For really big values `bigInt(20).pow(200)` combined with really **big Bases** like 100*(and more) it seems to be pretty accurate again.

Greetings, jonas.

Comment: Is this acurate?

Comment: @JonasW. This will only be accurate to the significand of JS floating points, which is 48 bits.

Comment: @kittsil i guess totally accurate results are often actually impossible for logarithms, so probably the bet answer we can get.